# For list sorting, is there a way to have multiple operator overloads with the same arguments?

Tags: c++, list, sorting, operator-overloading

## Summary

I have a std::list of type Process*

```
class Process
{
// non essential stuff

// vars I want to sort by
int pid;
int burstTime;
int rBurstTime;
int priority;
}
```

I want to overload the < operator for sorting my list via list::sort()

```
bool operator<(Process const& p) {return this.priority < p.priority}
bool operator<(Process const& p) {return this.burstTime < p.burstTime}
// etc.
```

The above seems impossible since there is no way to determine the difference between the two (or am I on the right track?).

## What I tried

I've tried something like

`bool operator<(Process const& p, <k>) {return this.priority < p.priority}`

where k is just any datatype/expected value that tells which overload to use, but this isn't possible since < overloads only take one argument.

Hopefully by now you can see what I am trying to do. Is there a C++ procedure for this that I am unaware of? I am a relatively new C++ programmer, so apologies if this is an easy fix.

Comment: [std::list's sort](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/sort) can take a comparison function/functor, you should use that instead (this is also true of [std::sort](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort))

Comment: Something like the example [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/sort/)? I saw this before posting this, but thought this was for built-in data types only.

Comment: priority and burstTime need to be different types so the compiler will know what you want. Otherwise, it "seems to be impossible" because it is. Create two different sub-classes that have just the one attribute each, priority and burstTime, and you might get it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved via Borgleader's comment:

std::list's sort can take a comparison function/functor, you should use that instead (this is also true of std::sort)